# Need to Remove all <font>, </font>, and <Font Color = "000000"> html tags using vba in excel 2010

Tags: html, excel, vba, fonts

I export test cases via a .csv file into excel with lots of HTML code. I have created a formatting macro in VBA to use for cleaning up layout, and removing of html tags. however, I'm having issues with the removing of the Font tag .  Can you assist me in the best way to remove the Font Tag? Is there a way to remove all font tags easily- FYI:including using the <*> for any remaning HTML code to be replaced with Chr(13) & Chr(10), so it's replacing  tag with with Chr(13) & Chr(10). Below is my Macro. I am fairly new to Macros and VBA, so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
 Columns("W:W").Select
    Cells.Replace What:="<ol>", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Cells.Replace What:="</ol>", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Cells.Replace What:="<ul>", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Cells.Replace What:="<<li>", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Cells.Replace What:="&amp;", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Cells.Replace What:="&nbsp;", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Cells.Replace What:="<font>", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Cells.Replace What:="</font>", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Cells.Replace What:="<font color="000000">", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Cells.Replace What:="<*>", Replacement:=Chr(13) & Chr(10), LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    Range("A:A,D:D,E:E,F:F,H:H,I:I,K:K,M:M,N:N,O:O,Q:Q,R:R,T:T,S:S,U:U,V:V").Select
    Range("V1").Activate
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=18
    Range("A:A,D:D,E:E,F:F,H:H,I:I,K:K,M:M,N:N,O:O,Q:Q,R:R,S:S,T:T,U:U,V:V,Y:Y").Select
    Range("Y1").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-45
    ActiveWindow.LargeScroll ToRight:=-2
    Range("A2").Select
 Cells.Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Columns("G:G").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 48.5
    Columns("H:H").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 48.5
 Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 48.5
    Columns("B:B").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
 Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 11.75
    Columns("C:C").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
 Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 11.75
    Columns("D:D").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
  Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 11.75
    Columns("E:E").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Columns("J:J").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your `"` within your strings with another `"`.

`"<font color="000000">"` should be `"<font color=""000000"">"`

Comment: Thanks nwhaught, that worked great, now if I could just figure out how to remove all the </span><span style> before and after text, while keeping the text I'd been good to go..

Comment: Does your `Cells.Replace` not work? What is happening?

Comment: Hi nwhaught - I am not sure this is doable. I don't know how to do this one, due to the <*> wildcard last replacement statement - replaces all remaining html tags with Chr(13) & Chr(10) so replaces any SPAN including a SPAN style tag w/carriage returns. I cannot figure out how to include in my script to remove all Span Code while leaving the text it surrounds - I have a bad case of "Stuck On Stupid"... how would I attach an example of the code for you?

Comment: That sounds like a separate question. Go ahead and create a new question--I'll keep an eye on the queue, and possibly someone else can help as well.